# request.getParameter("String") always returns null. Why?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

```
// jsp snippet
<button name="TesterButton" value="TesterButton" onClick="location.href='TesterServlet';">
```

*Servlet Snippet of class TesterServlet*

```
writer.println( (String)request.getParameter("TesterButton") ); // always returns null
```

The above servlet always returns null. Why does it return null ?

Comment: This is simply not how HTML forms work. That said, you're not even _using_ a form, since you're navigating with an `onclick`. What exactly _are_ you trying to do?

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL i want to send the value of the button to servlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working exactly as you told the code to do: changing the window location to the given URL. So, no surprises.

What you *actually* want should be coded as follows:

```html
<form action="TesterServlet">
    <input type="submit" name="TesterButton" value="TesterButton" />
</form>
```

Or if you really insist in using JS for this for some reason:

```html
<button name="TesterButton" value="TesterButton" onclick="location.href='TesterServlet?TesterButton=TesterButton';">
```

Note that the use of `onClick` instead of `onclick` indicates that you're possibly reading outdated or poor HTML resources/examples.

#### See also:

- [HTMLdog - HTML beginner tutorial](http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/)
- [W3 HTML forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)

Answer (score 1):

The button is not send in the request even if is inside a form.

UPDATE:

If you want to send the value of the clicked button (kinda strange) you need to use a hidden element and set the value before call the servlet:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidButtonValue" />
    <button id="TesterButton" value="TesterButton" onclick="document.getElementById('hidButtonValue').value=this.value; location.href='TesterServlet';"
</form>
```

Now you can call the hidden in your servlet

```
writer.println( (String)request.getParameter("hidButtonValue") );
```

Also, it would be better to encapsulate the `onclick` code in a JavaScript function.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Why would you need to send the button? If you need to send a value that you don't want to show to the user, you can use a hidden element

Comment: i want to send the value of the button after the user clicks that button

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way would be using a form with a hidden field:

```
<form action="TesterServlet">
    <input type="hidden" name="testField" id="test" value="SomeValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then in your servlet:

```
writer.println( (String)request.getParameter("testField") ); // Should return "SomeValue"
```